# How many machine instructions are needed for a function call in C?

Tags: c, performance, gcc, instructions, machine-code

I'd like to know how many instructions are needed for a function call in a C program compiled with gcc for x86 platforms from start to finish.

Comment: gcc -g test.c, gdb a.out, disas main

Comment: How many instructions to set up the call? To set up and clean up afterwards (which may happen in the caller or in the callee, depending on the calling convention)? In any case, the exact number depends on the number of parameters passed.

Comment: @Erik You missed the count instructions step!!  ;-)

Comment: @David Heffernan: Good point. Can't assume *anything* :P

Comment: It could even be 0 if the compiler decides to inline the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a really tricky question that's hard to answer and it may vary.

First of all in the caller it is needed to pass the parameters, depending on the type this will vary, in most cases you will have a **push** instruction for each parameter.

Then, in the called procedure the first instructions will be to do the allocation for local variables. This is usually done in 3 operations:

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP, ESP
SUB ESP, xxx
```

You will have the assembly code of the function after that.

Following the code but before the return, the ebp and esp will be restored:

```
MOV ESP, EBP
POP EBP
```

Lastly, you will have a **ret** instruction that depending on the calling convention will dealocate the parameters of the stack or it will leave that to the caller. You can determine this if the **RET** is with a number as parameter or if the parameter is 0, respectively. In case the parameter is 0 you will have **POP** instructions in the caller after the **CALL** instruction.

Comment: Who said anything about parameters? :-)

Answer (score 3):

- Write some code.
- Compile it.
- Look at the disassembly.
- Count the instructions.

The answer will vary as you vary the number and type of parameters, calling conventions etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect at least one

```
CALL Function
```

unless it is inlined, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `-mno-accumulate-outgoing-args` and `-Os` (or `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2`, or 3 on 64-bit), then the overhead is exactly one `push` per argument word-sized argument, one `call`, and one `add` to adjust the stack pointer after return.

Without `-mno-accumulate-outgoing-args` and with default 16-byte stack alignment, gcc generates code that's roughly the same speed but roughly five times larger for function calls, for no good reason.